# Finding minimum value of $AX+XB-XX'$

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Question: There are two points on a plane: $A$ and $B$. Find point $X$ such that value of expression $AX+XB-XX'$ is minimal where $X'$ is orthonormal projection of $X$ on $AB$

Tip to task is to draw equilateral triangle $ABC$. I'm looking for elementary solution. Using algebra I found that the sought point $X$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$. It seems to ma that it is a typical Heron's 'shortest distance' problem with the difficulty of subtraction which I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will be divided into $2$ parts.

(i) First we show that for minimal $AX+BX-XX'$,  $X'$ has to be the mid-point of $AB$.

[image]

Let $X$ be any point on the plane, draw a (red) line parallel to $AB$.

Notice that any point on the (red) line has the same distance to $AB$.

Therefore to minimize $AX+BX-XX'$ is the same as to minimize $AX+BX$.

From reflection principle, we know that the miminum is attained at point $P$  where $\alpha = \beta$, i.e. $AP=BP$.

Thus $XX'$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. Equivalently $X'$ is the mid-point of $AB$.
$$$$
(ii)  Take any point $X$ on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, we can always mark a point $C$ on the perpendicular bisector such that $X$ becomes an inner point of $\Delta ABC.$

[image]
Notice that  $AX+BX-XX'= AX+BX+CX-CX'$.

Since $CX'$ is fixed, minimizing $AX+BX-XX'$ is the same as minimizing $AX+BX+CX$.

But the minimum is attained at point $F$ (the Torricelli's point of $\Delta ABC$) where $\angle AFB=\angle BFC=\angle CFA=120^{\text o}$.

As seen in the figure, the point $F$ is the same for all $\Delta ABC$ so long as $CA=CB$.

Thus the minimum is attained at the fixed point $F$ here.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung While you are right, it is not clear why exactly you chose equilateral triangle to be a part of a solution since any isosceles triangle would work the same way. I know that it is a tip, but that remark calls for more holistic approach to the problem

Comment: @user2k2k You are right. I am going to rewrite my answer.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung What I mean by "work the same way" is that both equilateral as well as any isosceles triangle built on $AB$ have the same Fermat's point

Comment: @user2k2k You are very right!!! Based on your comment, I am going to rewrite my answer again!

Answer (score 0):

If we fix $XX'$ (let's call it $a$), $X$ is on a horizontal line with distance $|XX'|$ from $AB$. then $|AX|+|BX|$ is minimal when $|AX|=|BX|$, because $$\min(|AX|+|BX|-|XX'|)=\min(|AX|+|BX|)-a=\min(\sqrt{a^2+|AX'|^2}+\sqrt{a^2+|AB-AX'|^2})-a$$
If we define $f(|AX'|)=\sqrt{a^2+|AX'|^2}+\sqrt{a^2+|AB-AX'|^2}$, we get that the minimum happens when $|AX'|=\frac{|AB|}{2}$, or in other words, $$|AX|=|BX|$$
We get that X is on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.
Out of all the points on this line, the intersection with $AB$ is the minimum

So $X$ is the middle of $AB$

Comment: Notice that in your choice of point $X$ expression +−′ assumes value $|AB|$ while when $X$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$ then said expression is equal to $\frac{sqrt(3)}{2} |AB|$ which is less than |AB|. Also I was pointing out that I'm looking for specifically geometric solution

Comment: @user2k2k you are right. We need to construct another function $f(h)=|AX|+|BX|-|XX'|=\sqrt(h^2+1$

Comment: @user2k2k you are right. We need to construct another function. Let's define $a=\frac{|AB|}{2}, h=|XX'|$, then $f(h)=|AX|+|BX|-|XX'|=2\cdot\sqrt{h^2+a}-h$ so we can get the minimum

Answer (score 0):

Note that to minimize $AX+XB-XX'$, $X$ has to be on the perpendicular bisector of $XX'$, otherwise we can shift $X$ towards the perpendicualr bisector to reduce value of $AX+XB$ while maintain the value of $XX'$ unchange.
Now suppose X is on the perpendicular bisector of $XX'$. Let $XX'$ and $AB$ be $x$ and $a$ respectively. Then
\begin{align*}
AX+XB-XX'&=2\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}-x\\
\end{align*}
By taking the derivative, we have
\begin{align*}
(2\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}-x)^{'}&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}}-1\\
\end{align*}
When the derivative is $0$, it reach its optimum.
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}}-1&=0\\
2x&=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}\\
3x^2&=\frac{a^2}{4}\\
x&=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{6}
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
AX+XB-XX'&=2\sqrt{{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{6}\right)}^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{6}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}
\end{align*}